# set multiple size limits for multiple fields in multer

Tags: node.js, express, multer

i have a router to handle form submission when multiple images and a video are uploaded, i need to set maximum size limit for images and video, the multer "limits" property accepts only one value, i tried to check for size inside the file filter like in the code below, but apparently i can't access the file's size until it's received..

```
const DIR = './uploads/';

const MAX_IMAGE_SIZE = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
const MAX_VIDEO_SIZE = 100 * 1024 * 1024;

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        fs.mkdirSync(DIR, { recursive: true });
        cb(null, DIR);
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        const fileName = file.originalname.toLowerCase().split(' ').join('-');
        cb(null, uuidv4() + '-' + fileName)
    }
});

let upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        if (file.fieldname == "images") {
            if (file.size > MAX_IMAGE_SIZE) {
                req.imageValidationError = "Image size can't exceed 2MB";
                return cb(req.fileValidationError);
            }
            if (file.mimetype == "image/png" || file.mimetype == "image/jpg" || file.mimetype == "image/jpeg" || file.mimetype == "image/webp") {
                cb(null, true);
            } else {
                req.imageValidationError = "Unsupported Image Type";
                return cb(req.fileValidationError);
            }
        }
        else if (file.fieldname == "video") {
            if (file.size > MAX_VIDEO_SIZE) {
                req.videoValidationError = "Video size can't exceed 100MB";
                return cb(req.fileValidationError);
            }
            if (file.mimetype == "video/ogg" || file.mimetype == "video/webm" || file.mimetype == "video/mp4" || file.mimetype == "video/ogv") {
                cb(null, true);
            } else {
                req.videoValidationError = "Unsupported video Type";
                return cb(req.fileValidationError);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

what can i do about this?
i'm thinking of having separate "upload" handlers for images and video..but that doesn't seem a clean approach